# ImageView makes images in the phone larger than the source image

Tags: android, imageview

I want to normally display an Image in an ImageView, though the problem is that it always becomes larger when I test it in my phone, Why?
Here is the src image:
[image]

xml code:

```
<ImageView 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:id="@+id/ButtonMemorizeLayoutNextSura"
 android:src="@drawable/quran_slidingdrawer_leftarrow_state"           
 android:layout_marginRight="10dip"   />
```

Comment: it will display imageview with the same height/width of image.

Comment: @PolamReddy in the Drawable folder

Comment: if it takes image from drawable it shows large. i am not sure, try to save in drawable-hdpi and remove from drawable and try to use that image.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely culprit is dpi scaling. Try moving the image to the `drawable-nodpi` folder (create one if it does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

you can try using scaleType in your ImageView.

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ButtonMemorizeLayoutNextSura" 
android:src="@drawable/quran_slidingdrawer_leftarrow_state" android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: Tried fitXY, but the same result.

Comment: sorry for that..o let me try your proble and i will tell if i got the working solution.but tell me from where you are getting the images sdcard/drawable??

Comment: you might be keeping image for any 1 size and say MDPI and testing the app in LDPI Device so thas why you are getting the feel that image becomes larger..cause if you using wrap-content then it will display the original size. TRY KEEPING 3 DIFFERENT SIZE IMAGES.

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag

```
Android:scale type = FIT_CENTER
```

OR TRY CENTER

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving height and width as wrap content, give height and width according to your wish using dip.